# Javascript class creating HTML elements

Tags: javascript

Im trying to write **class** that adds **HTML** elements.

Here is my code:

```
class element{
    constructor(text){
        this.text = text;
    }
    get div(){
        return this.addElementDiv
    }
    addElementDiv(text){
        this.element = document.createElement("div");
        this.element.innerHTML = this.text;
        document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    }
    get p(){
        return this.addElementP
    }
    addElementP(text){
        this.element = document.createElement("p");
        this.element.innerHTML = this.text;
        document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    }
}


const myForm = new element();

myForm.div("myowntext")
myForm.p("myowntext2")
```

My problems:

1. It creates those elements but it doesnt display my text inside of element.
2. I can create div or p separately, what if i would like to create p in div like that:

   ```
   myForm.div.p("my text inside of p")
   ```

or even like that:

```
   myForm.div.p("my text from div","my text from p")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Change to this.element.innerHTML = text;
2. You can't do that since you're appending new elements to body. You can pass a CSS selector to the constructor, and instead of using document.body.appendChild, select that element to append the new element.

```
<div class="lets-select-this"></div>
```

```
class element{
    constructor(text, selector){
        this.text = text;
        this.selector = selector;
    }
    get div(){
        return this.addElementDiv
    }
    addElementDiv(text, selector){
        this.element = document.createElement("div");
        this.element.innerHTML = text;
        let parent = document.querySelector(selector);
        parent.appendChild(this.element);
    }
    get p(){
        return this.addElementP
    }
    addElementP(text, selector){
        this.element = document.createElement("p");
        this.element.innerHTML = text;
        let parent = document.querySelector(selector);
        parent.appendChild(this.element);
    }
}


const myForm = new element();

myForm.div("myowntext", ".lets-select-this")
myForm.p("myowntext2", ".lets-select-this div")
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to `bind` the methods you're returning like this.  I deleted the `this.text` field because you apparently want to use the supplied text parameter on your methods instead (which wasn't being used in your example).

```
class element{
    constructor(){
    }
    get div(){
        return this.addElementDiv.bind(this);
    }
    addElementDiv(text){
        this.element = document.createElement("div");
        this.element.innerHTML = text;
        document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    }
    get p(){
        return this.addElementP.bind(this);
    }
    addElementP(text){
        this.element = document.createElement("p");
        this.element.innerHTML = text;
        document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    }
}
```

It might make more sense to avoid the unnecessary redirection though.  You could just do this:

```
    div(text){
        this.element = document.createElement("div");
        this.element.innerHTML = text;
        document.body.appendChild(this.element);
    }
    // No need for addElementDiv function.
```

Answer (score 0):

you example won't create text inside div/p tags, as you don't pass any text to them. for this to work, you have to pass text to the constructor as you're setting inner html to be the result of this.text and not text as passed argument.

I don't understand why you're using the getters in such way, you can directly call addElementDiv/addElementP and pass your text as argument, otherwise if you want them to be private and use getters as your public API, maybe you assign a public properties to have the created DOM elements instead.

Cheers